# ¿Es posible hacer varios toString() de una misma clase en c#?

Tags: c#

Tengo una clase definida la cual quiero que tome dos métodos toString(), sobre todo por estética del programa, quiero que en un caso se muestren varias variables(para un listbox) y para otro solo una variable(para un combobox), de la siguiente manera.

O de que manera resultaría mejor, sobre todo porque agrego el objeto como tal a los componentes (listbox y combobox).

```
public class ZonaSistema
{

//Declaración de atributos
private int idZona;
private int numeroZona;
private string descripcionZona;
private int particionZona; 

    //Sobrecarga al método toString
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Zona: " + this.numeroZona + "\tDescripción: " + this.descripcionZona + "\tPartición: " + this.particionZona;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Zona: " + this.numeroZona;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Solo puedes hacer un override al metodo `ToString()`, pero puedes hace las sobre cargas que requieras, por ejemplo:

```
public class Impuesto
{
    public int Valor { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Valor.ToString();
    }
    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return Valor.ToString(format);
    }
    ///puedes seguir sobre cargando el metodo ToString según requieras
}
```

Para tu caso te recomendaría que definas una propiedad que retorne el nombre completo y esa propiedad la muestres en tu listbox. Tu Clase podría quedar de esta manera:

```
public class ZonaSistema
{
    private int IdZona { get; set; }
    private int NumeroZona { get; set; }
    private string DescripcionZona { get; set; }
    private int ParticionZona { get; set; }

    public string NombreCompleto
    {
        get
        {
            return $"Zona: {NumeroZona}\tDescripción: {DescripcionZona }\tPartición: {ParticionZona}";
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Zona: " + NumeroZona;
    }
}
```